# Have bio-organic weapons ever gotten past the testing phase?

Tags: resident-evil

I'm not really up to speed on most of RE lore; I've only completed 4 and 5. Reading through plot summaries for most of the other entries, it doesn't seem like the zombie/monster plagues ever get sold and used as actual bio-organic weapons though. Is there a instance in the series where they're actually **bought** and used, instead of just testing them on the locals, or having an accidental outbreak?

This can be about any RE media, but preferably the games.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, there's nothing that explicitly stated that BOWs were ever bought and then used as weapons.**
Below is a list of all the BOW outbreaks I could find to back that up. Only the incidents in Revelations and Damnation come close, but the method of aquisition of the BOWs is vague in those.

**[Arklay Mountains](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Mansion_Incident), USA - 1998**
*RE0, RE1/REmake*
Sabotage. Virus gets loose, people die, mansion is blown up.

**[Raccoon City](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Raccoon_City_Destruction_Incident), USA - 1998**
*RE3, RE2, Operation Raccoon City, Outbreak 1&2, 4D-Executer (CG film)*
Accident. An indirect consequence of the Arklay Mountains incident, laboratory waste spills over into Raccoon City. People die, city is blown up.

**[Sheena Island](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Sheena_Island_incident) - 1998**
*Survivor*
Sabotage. Done to silence anyone who might tell of Umbrella's nefarious deeds. People die, island is blown up.

**[Rockfort Island](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Rockfort_Island_Incident)/[Antarctic base](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Antarctic_Outbreak) - 1998**
*Code Veronica*
Sabotage. Wesker tries capturing someone from the island, but bombs it first. This releases a virus held there. Wesker also releases other BOWs.

**[Atlantic Facility](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Atlantic_Facility_outbreak) - 2002**
*Dead Aim*
Accident. People die, facility is blown up.

**[South America](http://residentevil.wikia.com/2002_South_American_incident) - 2002**
*Darkside Chronicles*
Byproduct of experimentation. Javier Hidalgo did probably did buy the virus, but used it to try to save his daughter. BOWs break loose due to carelessness (I think - feel free to correct me on this). People die, nothing is blown up.
Does not qualify. The virus is purchased, but there's no deliberate use of the BOWs as weapons (I should play the game to confirm this).

**[Cuacasus mountains](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Caucasus_outbreak), Russia - 2003**
*Umbrella Chronicles*
Sabotage. This is Wesker doing away with the last remnant of Umbrella. People die, but the facility surprisingly does not explode.

**[Spain](http://residentevil.wikia.com/2004_Abduction_of_the_President%27s_Daughter) - 2004**
*RE4*
Attempt to gain control over the president of the United States with homegrown parasites.
Does not qualify, as there's been no purchase, just an excavation of the parasites and purposeful conversion of the locals.

**[Terragrigia](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Terragrigia_Panic) and [the Queen Zenobia](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Queen_Zenobia_Incident), Mediterranean Sea - 2004/2005**
*Revelations*
Deliberate. Unknown how the virus was aquired. People die, a city and 3 cruise ships are blown up.

**[Harvardville Airport](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Harvardville_Airport_outbreak), USA - 2005**
*Degeneration (CG film)*
Sabotage. Passenger on a plane is infected, plane crashlands, zombies spill out, people die, the vaccine is blown up.
The saboteur tries to sell the virus to terrorists afterwards (the attack itself was a sales pitch of sorts), but is caught before he can.

**[Kijuju](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Kijuju_Autonomous_Zone_Incident) - 2008/2009**
*RE5*
Byproduct of experimentation. As far as I can tell, Wesker and Irving were using Kijuju as a testbed for Las Plagas derivatives. Irving intends to eventually sell them, while Wesker wants to use Uroboros to wipe the world of most of its population. Both die before they can.

**[Eastern Slavic Republic](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Eastern_Slav_Civil_War) - 2010**
*Damnation (CG film)*
BOWs used as weapons in a civil war. It's never specified how the BOWs are aquired. It's implied they could have gotten them from the black market. Large part of the population seems to be wiped out.

**[Multiple outbreaks](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Resident_Evil_6/plot) - 2012/2013**
*RE6*
Deliberate. The work of Neo Umbrella, which did not need to buy the viruses. One city is blown up.

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly RE4 and RE5 showed that BOWs (bio organic weapons) have a wide application of uses. What people don't know is that most of the BOW that Umbrella and Tri-Cell have experimented and tested with are actually based on ancient genetic materials that are only known to select few.

RE4 introduced the Plaga parasites which have been sealed away for centuries because of the cults abuse of the mind control power. This Unsealing leads to the creation of the Ganado, which means the herd, as the entire population of a Spanish town was controlled by the new cult making them perfect soldiers that although lack higher thinking can still carry out easy tasks and masquerade as day to day village life.

RE5 showed what Tri-Cell had done with the Plagas by adding leech DNA into their makeup it made victims retain higher thinking and use of technology while still obeying and working as a group to subdue and overcome problems with no concern for their survival, although these 'Majini' tended to be more psychotic in nature due to a pack mentality which would make them attack anybody who not currently infected.

In RE6 which shows the 'other' side of the coin so to speak, it shows various different groups using BOWs to further their causes. Amongst the chaos of a Viral warhead attack on Washington D.C. with an airborne gaseous variation of the new strain, the C-virus, which causes wide spread zombie infestation.

other terrorist groups have bought the C-virus in liquid form for direct injection into the blood stream which results in the creation of a J'avo (translates as Devil). An individual that infects himself will retain full mental ability while gaining enhanced physical abilities such as strength, reflexes and regenerative capabilities. The cost to this upgrade however is extreme facial mutations such as growing new eye clusters, extreme skin ripping and scaring and discoloration. A Japanese triad style gang employs the use of white decorative ceramic masks to hide this though and appear and act normal until provoked. A further mutation caused by the virus which cannot be hidden is caused by extreme trauma, a J'avo can regenerate lost limbs and extreme damage through uncontrolled mutation, a lost arm will explode into a huge scythe arm or organic shell shield, blowing of a leg will cause you to grow spider-like jumping legs. It's possible for J'avo to cause zombie infections as they are C-virus carrier's which can cause secondary BOW out breaks.

I hope this clarifies some details for you. I tried not to include 'spoilers', the attack on Washington is the actual start of RE6.

Comment: My answer obviously only includes the 'humanoid' examples. Not the creatures and boss types, which are the more violent uncontrollable breeds. I could add examples if you require, the earliest example is obviously the Cerberus 'zombie dogs' that patrol the Spencer mansion in RE1!

Comment: Alright, I'm familiar with the effects of most of the viruses/parasites, but this is about their use. You've covered the "what" of RE4 through 6, but I'm interested in the "how" of the whole series. And this is about the non-humanoid creatures too, such as the Hunters.